# gd php как проверить на анимацию webp? и как (чем) ресайзить (ЕСЛИ ресайз нужен) webp с сохранением анимации

Tags: php, анимация, gd, resize, webp

Как проверить на анимацию **webp**?, и как/чем  ресайзить (ЕСЛИ ресайз нужен) webp с **сохранением** анимации.

Чуток поясню про "если ресайз нужен": Сие значит - если ширина или высота картинки (любой картинки!) меньше размера в который происходит ресайз всех картинок, то картинка не ресайзится. Почему? Та потому что после ресайза она окажется больше оригинала. Это противоречит здравому смыслу ресайза. Ну и еще несколько заморочек с картинками у меня есть, но это прямого отношения к данному вопросу не имеет.

С gif у меня всё в порядке. А вот с webp, та еще и с анимированным... ???